What are the functions for the components in this expression pedal port circuit?
This is the design that the Roland A49 MIDI controller uses:

Here is the design I would use if I hadn't seen Roland's design:

What is the function of the extra components?
My thoughts:

The 1k resistor on the 3.3V is that it serves some kind of protection against over current caused by plugging in a faulty pedal, or something that's not even a pedal but has a jack (to make it dumb-proof.)
The capacitor as well as L2 and L5 probably function as low-pass filters.
D1 is ESD protection

Are these assumptions correct?
What about the other 1k and the 100k resistor? I don't see why they are needed.

your design has no input

@jsotola What makes you say that? OPs design has an explicit potentiometer drawn. The commercial device has a detachable potentiometer in the form of a pedal to control the instrument, not drawn because it depicts the pedal interface.

@Justme there is no audio input ... I might be misunderstanding the purpose of the circuit

@jsotola It's not an audio input. It's an input for a potentiometer, buffered to something like MCU ADC, to sense the position of the pedal as voltage to control something - anything like volume, vibrato depth, tremolo, reverb level, etc. Synthesizers have had these since the 80's.

R12 makes sense as protection to limit current to 3.3mA if you plug in something incorrect.
L1 and L4 are sort of low pass filters. However they look like ferrite beads, which means they are intended to block RF frequencies, not audible frequencies. And they may be either keeping external noise outside, or preventing internal noise from radiating outside. We cannot know the real reason.
D1 is likely not for ESD protection, at least not alone for that. There's already R16 and C34 that are effective as RC filter for ESD and D1 will further clamp it. However if you feed in too large voltages by plugging again wrong things into this device such as audio output, the R16 and D1 limit/clamp the voltage to safe values to prevent damage.
R14 is likely just a default pull-up to set the voltage if nothing is connected.
R4 may be due to where signal goes next. It might be a sampling ADC and op-amps may not be stable with capacitive loads or jolts of sampling current being drawn at high speeds.

Do you mean L1 and L4 are lowpass filters? I don't see an L2 or L5.

@Hearth Yes, what are the odds of two typos (but they were both +1 or shifted right by one key).
